# Concatenate strings in UrlMappings?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to create separate controllers for admin in my application. So far I've got something like this :

```
"/admin/article/$action?/$id?"(controller:"adminArticle")
"/admin/comment/$action?/$id?"(controller:"adminComment")
```

And so on for all the admin controllers. I would like to make it simpler, tried :

```
"/admin/$controller?/$action?/$id?"(controller:"admin" + controller[0].toUpperCase() + controller[1..-1])
```

and

```
"/admin/$controller/$action?/$id?"(controller:"admin$controller")
```

but neither of this solutions worked. Have you any idea how can I make this mappings more dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the controller value if you use a closure.

```
/$mode/$contr"{
  action = "someAction"
  controller = {
    if (params.mode == "api") {
      return params.contr+"API"
    } 
    else {
      return params.contr
    }
  }
  constraints {
    mode inList:["menu", "api"]
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should not use the word "controller". I didn't try it, but this could work:

```
"/admin/$contr/$action?/$id?"(controller:"admin$contr") // if first letter of contr is upper case
```